# Subgraph with "dangling edges"?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I was wondering if there is a notion in graph theory where one can have a subgraph such that the endpoints of all of the edges in the subgraph are not necessarily included in the vertex set of the subgraph. In a sense, one can think of the subgraph as having dangling edges. Is there a term for this graph theoretical object?

Comment: A subgraph is a graph for what I imagine is any sensible definition of "subgraph", and in particular every edge has two vertices. What are the vertices of a dangling edge?

Comment: I was thinking that we could define such a subgraph, with dangling edges, as a subgraph with edge set $(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4)$ but with a vertex set of ${1,2,3}$ excluding vertex $4$.

Comment: As has been pointed out, it won't be a "subgraph" in a strict sense, but that doesn't mean it can't be a useful concept. I believe I have seen something like this in a talk involving phylogenetic trees, I'll try and dig around.

Comment: @pjs36 Does the concept of a "half-edge" match the description in the original question?